# How to avoid Switch case on input values

Tags: javascript, json, function, optimization, switch-statement

I asked myself a question to optimize my code in JavaScript.
I am currently doing something like this :

Data.json :

```
{
  "House" :
    { "bedroom"  : "4" }
    { "kitchen"  : "1" }
    { "bathroom" : "2" }
}
```

Choose.js :

```js
var Data = require('./Data.json');

printData = function(id) {
  console.log(getData(id));
}

getData = function(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case "bedroom":
      return Data.House.bedroom;
    case "kitchen":
      return Data.House.kitchen;
    case "bathroom":
      return Data.House.bathroom;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

And I would like to know if we could optimize this with a special syntax, for example if we simply have :

```js
var Data = require('./Data.json');

printData = function(id) {
  console.log(Data.House.{ id });
}
```

I know this might be a stupid question for you but it would be helpful if you tell me if it's possible or not. I wish I could avoid very long Switch Cases in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: `return Data.House[id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` notation

```
printData=function(id){
    return Data.House[id];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

```js
var Data = {
  "House" : { 
    "bedroom"  : "4", 
    "kitchen"  : "1",
    "bathroom" : "2" 
  }
};

getData = function(id) {
  return Data.House[id];
}

console.log(getData('bedroom'));
console.log(getData('kitchen'));
console.log(getData('xxx'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getData=function(id){
   if(Data.House.hasOwnProperty(id)) return Data.House[id];
    return '';
}
```